# How to fix movement menu on load page?

Tags: css, css-transitions, transform

I have animation with using transform:translate(-100%) and transition, but when i load page my block is moving  from 0% to -100%;
in normal condition she have to have transform:translate(-100%) and when checkbox is checked - transform:translate(0%)
It works well but on load is moving from o to -100%

https://katehrybkova.github.io/ETmenu/index.html - link on github-page
https://github.com/katehrybkova/ETmenu - source

```css
.menuBlock {
  background-color: #35393b;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px 0;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: 1s;

}
#idishka:checked~.menuBlock {
  transform: translateX(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The animation starts with `.menuBlock` at `left: 0`, that's why `transform: translateX(-100%)` starts fading it to the left.

Maybe you can replace `translateX` function with `left`, because you have `.menuBlock` with fixed width.

This is the final code:

```
.menuBlock {
    background-color: #35393b;
    height: 100vh;
    color: white;
    padding: 25px 0;
    width: 400px;
    transition: 1s;
    position: absolute;
    left: -400px;
}
#idishka:checked ~ .menuBlock {
    left: 0;
}
```

I don't recommend you using *fixed* widths (in pixels), for responsivity issues ;)